# Multiple Datasets in Bar Chart -> Bars out of Bound

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I'm trying to display data in a bar chart using chart.js. I'm using multiple datasets so I can show the data id as the lable of the dataset. I have only one datapoint in each dataset and the x-axis displays the time. I want to display 15 datasets. The problem is, when displaying more than one datasets some bars get out of bound. [How it looks and how I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BtF5.jpg). I

I tried the barPercentage and the categoryPercentage options without any success.

Here is what I got so far:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="node_modules\chart.js\dist\Chart.bundle.js"></script>
    <style>
        canvas{
            height:120px !important;
            width:302px !important;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <canvas id= "myChart" width=400 height=400></canvas>
    </div>
        <script>
            <!-- My script for the Chart -->
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the script that handels the chart:

```js
//The array of datasets that I want to display
var datasetarray = [{
label: 'Secounds needed for dummy build',
data: [{x:"19700101T0001",y:20}],
backgroundColor: ['rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)'],
    borderColor: ['rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'],
borderWidth: 1
}
, //Some more datasets
,{
label: 'Secounds needed for dummy build',
data: [{x:"19710315T0001",y:20}],
backgroundColor: ['rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)'],
    borderColor: ['rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'],
borderWidth: 1
}];

//Creating the Chart
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        datasets: datasetarray
    },
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        legend: {display: false},
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type:'time',
                distribution: 'series',             
                barPercentage: 0.9,
                categoryPercentage: 0.9,
                bounds:'data',
                offset:false,
                ticks:{source: 'labels'}
                }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    suggestedMax: 100
                    ,suggestedMin: 20
                    ,beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT: Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/npuwyj4e/) that may help you helping me. Thanks in advance :)